# Using Dissolve inputs in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, dissolve

I'm trying to build a model in modelbuilder, and as part of that, I'd like to use the dissolve tool on a feature class created/modified after some previous steps. However, when I try to connect this feature class, I'm not given the option to use it as an input, only a precondition. Is this a normal problem with Dissolve? Is there something specific that the table needs to be in order to perform the Dissolve? I've attached a snippet of the part of my model leading up to the problem to help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the "[make feature layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000006p000000)" tool.

Connect the output from "Calculate Field" to "Make Feature Layer".  You should then be able to connect the output of "Make Feature Layer" into the Dissolve tool.

Comment: To compliment Dans answer if you look at the syntax section of the help file for the dissolve tool it states the input is a FeatureLayer and this is why you need to use the make layer tool.

Comment: I can't connect the Calculate Field output to Make Feature Layer. My only option is Precondition. The same happens with Create Feature Class (@Hornbydd)

Comment: @BabbA are you able to put up another image of your model with data in it, so that the model segments are coloured in.  It sounds like there might be an error in the model before you get to the Make Feature Layer tool.